# Como selecciono una imagen por mes en Google earth engine

Tags: google-app-engine

qeuría seleccionar una imagen por mes, como se hace con Google Earth engine?Tengo el siguiente codigo

var IMGSentinel= ee.ImageCollection ('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
  .filterDate ('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01')

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con el producto que estás eligiendo también hay que filtrar por una geometría. Si no lo haces, te daría un error en tiempo de ejecución ya que intenta acumular todas las imágenes para la superficie terrestre (mucho más del límite que es 5000). El script a continuación produce las doce imágenes requeridas para un punto arbitrario en USA.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-99.42, 38.4);

var IMGSentinel = ee.ImageCollection ('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate ('2019-01-01', '2019-05-01')
  .filterBounds(pt);

print(IMGSentinel);

var list = IMGSentinel.toList(IMGSentinel.size());

print(list);

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1");
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var monthly = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(months.map(function(m) {
  var filtered = IMGSentinel.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: m,
    field: 'month'
  }));

  return filtered.mean()
      .set('month', m);
}));

print(monthly);

var image_first = ee.Image(monthly.first())
  .select('B1');

Map.centerObject(pt, 9);
Map.addLayer(image_first, {min: 2825.5, max: 5118.5}, 'image_first');
```

Después de ejecutado el script se obtiene el resultado esperado: una imagen por mes expresada como la media de cada píxel. Sólo por verificación, se imprime en la vista de mapas de GEE la banda 'B1' de la primera imagen.

El link al script es el siguiente:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/26ec0f38fd7bd45b82c9ae0e35a7e766